# how to scrape text in double quotes in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to scrape the text which is "12,999" using 
scrapy selector

```
first.css('div._1vC4OE _2rQ-NK::text').extract_first()
```

The above selector works fine for every other tags ex:

```
<test-tag> this is being scraped </test-tag>
```

But It fails(does not display anything) while scraping this:

```
    <div class="_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK" data-reactid="472">
     <!-- react-text: 473 -->"₹"<!-- /react-text -->
     <!-- react-text: 474 -->"12,999"<!-- /react-text -->
    </div>
```

I think this is failing coz of the presence of (""). How do I scrape the text in between?